# CGAL: Manually Create Point Set for Shape Detection

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm trying to use CGAL's shape detection algorithm according to the ["Basic Planar Shape Detection" example](https://doc.cgal.org/4.13.1/Point_set_shape_detection_3/index.html#Point_set_shape_detection_3Usage_minimal) in CGAL 4.13.1. However, instead of reading-in the data from a file with

```
CGAL::read_xyz_points(stream,
      std::back_inserter(points),
      CGAL::parameters::point_map(Point_map()).
      normal_map(Normal_map()))
```

I would like to load my points from an existing `pcl::PointCloud` to the necessary CGAL type. I'm just not sure how to create this CGAL type. According to the example (excerpt)

```
typedef std::pair<Kernel::Point_3, Kernel::Vector_3> Point_with_normal;
typedef std::vector<Point_with_normal> Pwn_vector;

Pwn_vector points;
typedef CGAL::Shape_detection_3::Efficient_RANSAC<Traits> Efficient_ransac;
EfficientRansac.set_input(points);
```

I just need to create the `Pwn_vector`. So my questions are

1. Can I just insert points in `Pwn_vector`?
2. What is the best way to get normals in CGAL? Is it `CGAL::jet_estimate_normals`?
3. Do I need the property maps for `Point_map` and `Normal_map`? I don't see how they are handed over to `Efficient_ransac`.
4. Anything else necessary?

I started with the following code:

```
  // Points with normals.
  cgal::Pwn_vector points;

  // load points from pcl cloud
  for (auto point : cloud.points) {
    cgal::Point_with_normal pwn;
    pwn.first = cgal::ShapeKernel::Point_3(point.x, point.y, point.z);
    points.push_back(pwn);
  }
```

(PCL is not of interest for this question since it's clear how to access the single coordinates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer point by point, I'd say:

1. You need to provide points and normals, so I'd say no.
2. You can use [jet]
   (https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/group__PkgPointSetProcessing3Algorithms.html#ga0cd0f87de690d4edf82740e856efa491), [pca](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/group__PkgPointSetProcessing3Algorithms.html#ga8c642da96a025ab32445aeb6cc219b0b)  or [vcm](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/group__PkgPointSetProcessing3Algorithms.html#ga020a2ee77849fc70cbbee93358222dff) normal estimation, as you wish.
3. You don't need them if you use the same types as in the example. The default values will do.
4. Basically you just need to fill the Pwn_vector with your points and the result of your normal estimation, and the rest should work exactly aas in the example.

Comment: Thanks. Estimating normals with pca and adding them to pwn worked pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer of mgimeno (which is correct), you don't necessarily need to copy the points. The interest of property maps is that you just need to provide a function `get()` that converts the `value_type` of your range to `CGAL::Point_3` (`CGAL::Vector_3` for normals) on the fly.

For example, for PCL, I imagine you'd do something like that (I'm not a user of PCL so this might be not be correct, but it's just to give you the idea):

```cpp
struct PCL_point_map
{
   typedef pcl::PointCloud::value_type key_type;
   typedef CGAL::Point_3<Kernel> value_type;
   typedef CGAL::Point_3<Kernel> reference;
   typedef boost::readable_property_map_tag category;

   friend reference get (const PCL_point_map&, const key_type& k)
   {
      return CGAL::Point_3<Kernel> (k.x, k.y, k.z);
   }
};
```

And something similar for normals (normals do need to be computed for shape detection to work, `CGAL::jet_estimate_normals` is a good choice for that). Then, if you just template the traits with your own maps, you can call directly the RANSAC algorithm on the PCL point cloud.